# How do I check if a post is password protected?

Tags: posts, single, password

I am checking to see if a post is password protected and if it is I will display the form, if not the post will be displayed. However after the password has been entered the user is not taken to view the post, I'm not sure why this is happening? Am I missing something in my code?

```
<?php if($post->post_password):
      echo get_the_password_form();
else: ?>
      echo content;
endif; ?>
```

Comment: try [post_password_required](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_password_required/) function since we need some cookies in this case.

Comment: Using that function does not work, the password form does not appear @MinhTri

Comment: @Neelan: did you check the function "get_the_password_form"? Worked it? Is the return value correct?